# what's the difference between PermissionsString="FullMask" vs AddAndCustomizePages vs ManageWeb?

Tags: check-permissions

what's the difference between PermissionsString="FullMask" vs AddAndCustomizePages vs ManageWeb ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find more details about permission string in this  [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690)

- FullMask - Grant all permissions.
- AddAndCustomizePages - Add, change, or delete HTML pages and Webpart pages.
- ManageWeb - Can perform all administration tasks for given sitecolection.